# A new connection is generated instead of using the new settings

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, network-manager, static-ip

I am trying to set up a static IP address using the nm-connection-editor tool. I select the currently-used wireless network, click edit, go to "IPV4 Settings", click add, enter a valid IP address, Netmask, Gateway, and DNS Server address. I click save.

I use nm-tool to check if the settings have been updated. They haven't. I re-connect to the network in question. Upon clicking "edit connections", I see that a new "connection" has been generated, named [name of old connection] 2 and the old one has been renamed to [oldname] 1. Restarting does not change this. I read that in order to let the GUI-based tool handle the network, I had to comment out all lines without "lo" in them in /etc/network/interfaces, so I tried that, but it did not change anything.

I have attempted to set up a static internal IP address by modifying /etc/network/interfaces, by adding this (same settings were used in nm-connection-editor):

```
 auto wlan0
 iface wlan0 inet static
 address 192.168.2.45
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.2.1
```

I have checked that it is the correct gateway and other settings multiple times. Adding those lines, however, only made nm-tool report that neither wlan0 nor eth0 are managed.

My questions:

- How am I supposed to use /etc/network/interfaces to setup a static IP address; specifically, how does that differ from what I am doing here? Obviously something is wrong.
- How am I supposed to use nm-connection-editor to setup a static IP address; specifically, what have I done wrong?
- If I haven't done anything wrong, is this a bug?
- What other information can I provide to help identify the problem?

I am running 32-bit Lubuntu 14.10 on a Dell Latitude D630 (Core 2 Duo processor, 2GB DDR2 RAM, Broadcom BCM4311 R01 wireless adapter).

---

UPDATE: Some bizarre stuff has been happening - each new "connection" (of the aforementioned form "[oldconnectionname] 1, 2, 3....") asks for the WPA password for the network each time it is created, but does not store it (in Wi-Fi Security). Despite this, every time I try reconnecting after the new "connection" is created, it does not re-ask for the password.

I have confirmed that setting a static IP address works doing the exact same thing (with different numbers, but also taken from the same output of nm-tool) with a different internet connection works - I successfully modified the connection properties to a different home wireless router connected to the same network. Which is strange, because previously changing the same settings on a windows machine connected to the same router experiencing troubles now had no difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

I am newer to linux but to manually configure your static ip should be as follows

---

sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces    or whatever editor you prefer

```
 auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.10.1
network 192.168.10.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255
```

---

follow changes with

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 then 
sudo ifup wlan0 
sudo dhclient
```

this is my scheme change addresses to match yours e.g. broadcast is .255 at then end
network would be .0 
Hope this helps.